# The Struts dispatcher cannot be found in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, glassfish-3

initially my jsp page is showed in proper way when i click on submit button it is showing class not found exception for sql library but then i add mysql library it is not showng jsp page and giving exception

`org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is 
 usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are 
 only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes
 the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]`

root cause

> The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag.

Please help me to resolve this

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" 
         version="2.5">

  <display-name>Struts2Example17</display-name>
  <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

this error is also coming

```
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
SEVERE: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider).
SEVERE: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
SEVERE: WebModule[/Struts2Example17]PWC1270: Exception starting filter struts2
```

errortrace

```
SEVERE: log4j:ERROR LogMananger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository.
SEVERE: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider).
SEVERE: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
SEVERE: WebModule[/Struts2Example17]PWC1270: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4685)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5377)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2000)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1651)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:269)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:294)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:462)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:126)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/D:/strts2/Struts2Example17/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8-sources.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:29:119
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:360)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:264)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:120)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.views.TagLibrary class:org.apache.struts2.dojo.views.DojoTagLibrary - bean - jar:file:/D:/strts2/Struts2Example17/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-dojo-plugin-2.1.8-sources.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:29:119
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:222)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:101)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:165)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dojo.views.DojoTagLibrary
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1519)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1369)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:146)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:193)
    ... 56 more
```

JSp file

```
 <%-- 
        Document   : statusdonationjsp
        Created on : Dec 20, 2011, 10:34:09 PM
        Author     : bhavishya
    --%>

    <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title>Pending Donation </title>

        </head>
        <body>

        Search String
              <s:form action="FindPendingDonation">
        <s:textfield name="detail" label="Name" />
            <s:select name="amounttype" list="{'Cash','Cheque'}" label="Paymet type" id="type" onchange="displayBlock()" />
            <s:select name="status" list="{'Paid','Unpaid'}" label="Status(Cash)" />
        <s:textfield name="amount" label="Amount" />
            <s:textfield name="responsibleparty" label="Bank Name/Responsible party"  id="cash" />
            <s:textfield name="chequeno" lable ="Cheque NO" id="chequeno"/>

            <s:submit />
    </s:form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you set the struts dispatcher as a filter in web.xml? Can you show the relevant portion?

Comment: need more information what configuration you have and URL you are hitting when this exception is occurring.One of the cause is hitting jsp page directly which have struts2 tags

Comment: if you have no proble then plz take session using team viewer

Comment: can you show me the URL you are hitting when you getting this problem? just cope and paste the URL from browser here

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Struts2Example17/statusdonationjsp.jsp

Comment: That will surely give the problem if you are using any struts2 tag in your jsp.i suggest you to go by Action way as it will ini the value stack for you

Comment: sorry i didn't get you .if i will not strts tage then how jsp page can be created

Comment: You can create simple jsp.Struts2 tags require that your request should go through the dispatcher which will init the request cycle and will prepare required data for struts2 tags to work.when you will hit jsp directly you are skipping that part and not letting struts2 to do any needed work for you hence you are getting that issue

Comment: i got the point but initially it was working fine

Comment: seems you are using `dono-plugin` and its jar is not included in the class-path make sure you have all required jars in the class-path

Comment: i tested the above code on my machine and everything working fine....can you let me know what jars you are using in all?

Comment: Have you installed the plugin required for integrating Struts2 with Netbeans? If not, have you included all the required jars and made an entry in web.xml. [Here are a few working netbeans examples.](http://www.onlinexamples.com/searchaction.action?idlabels=18&label=struts2)

Answer (score 2):

As per the discussion problem seems to be due to directly accessing the JSP page and not letting the Struts2 Dispatcher to init the request processing cycle and create needed value stack and other parameters.

Best way in Struts or MVC2 based architecture is to go by Action even if your action is not doing any work for you.

Struts2 provides out of the box functionality for this, if we are not providing any action class in the configuration file Struts2 will create an Action class for us on the fly and will return SUCCESS as result.so we need to do following in our struts.xml file

```
<action name="myaction">
  <result>/statusdonationjsp.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**Updated**

As per the new stack-trace seems that dojo plugin in missing from  the class path.Please include struts2-dojo-plugin jar in your class path

Comment: @user1047873: i asked you to post your jsp file and your added error messages showed its unable to load dojo-plugin.is this jar is there in your class path?

Comment: when firestly i run the code every thing is working fine but next time it is showing error

Comment: i have add jsp file just scroll down

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem was your web.xml file .

Just Change Your old filter tag to new one with one modification

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
  </filter>
```

So, it should work for this solution. However if it's not work, better way is just copy struts-blank.war file from this link [struts.war](http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror/struts/examples). According to your version here i mean 2.x versions, download 2.x one rar file and extract it & in that copy struts-balnk.war and import to your `ide` `for eg:eclipse` in that directory structure under web content copy your jsp file 100% it will work.

Comment: struts.war link broken?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the importing jars have the same struts2 version. I got this error because of

> Struts2-Core-2.3.15.3.jar

and

> struts2-dojo-plugin-2.3.20

I was able to resolve this by using version 2.3.15.3 for both jars.

Answer (score 1):

This Exception may be due to 1)In Web.xml filter not defined or 2)The server doesn't look up the web.xml for Filter Dispatcher. Just clean the project, clean the server and restart the server. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I have the multiple configuration files in my project(other files are included in the default struts.xml file).
The included file names in default struts.xml must match with the < package name > of individual included xmls and should not be same for all the included files. Giving the correct  in each included xmls resolved the issue.
This link can be useful - http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/struts/splitting-modularizing-struts2-configuration-file

Answer (score 0):

Please check your project structure, i.e web.xml is under WEB-INF folder, all view is under webcontent folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same problem, also try changing jar file as mention in above comment,  but not solve the issue.

finally, i found typing mistake in my struts.xml file, for `action` tag in `package` tag. for `type` attribute of `action` tag i have given success or error.
Actually, there must be `name` attribute instead of `type`. for `type` used for redirect page.

also in `package` tag there `namespace` attribute and i wrongly type nameSpace, 
for this reasons i'm facing "The Struts dispatcher cannot be found".

but after i correcting my mistakes it's running well no issue...so just check your struts.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your URL pattern from `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>`.